# Is it possible to use Materializecss without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

I would like to use [materializecss](http://materializecss.com) without jQuery. For example, I want to do the following without the use of jQuery:

```
$('.chips-initial').material_chip({
    data: [{
      tag: 'Apple',
    }, {
      tag: 'Microsoft',
    }, {
      tag: 'Google',
    }],
  });
```

Thanks

Comment: http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html One last thing to note is that you have to import jQuery before importing materialize.js!

Comment: @tuna Which is a shame, since jQuery use seems to be slowing down nowadays. Every framework out there that relies on it has opened issues asking this very thing.

Answer (score 9):

Starting with Materialize 1.0.0, jQuery is not a dependency anymore.

See https://medium.com/@materializecss/materialize-to-1-0-and-beyond-e0233b8ac15

Previous releases still rely on jQuery. Alternatively you can use Cash by Ken Wheeler.

Comment: We plan to move to ES6 components and stop using jQuery.

Comment: I thought Web Component support was still pretty thin. Maybe it's ok though with the polyfill

Comment: I do not mean webcomponents, just pure ES6 babelized for browsers.

Comment: Jquery was good when ReactJS and other Angular Vue etc doesn't exist. But now it looks like a legacy of the past that the utility's become more marginal each day, relatively to the need to download the library inside the code -hence the important size-wasting regarding to the part of the library really indispensable.

Comment: Materialize 1 does not use jQuery

Answer (score 8):

Since [version 1.0.0](http://next.materializecss.com/) you can.

```
const elem = document.querySelector('.chips');
const instance = M.Chips.init(elem, options);
```

[List of possible options](http://next.materializecss.com/chips.html#options) for the chips.

For Angular2+ you'll need:

```
npm install materialize-css
```

In **package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "materialize-css": "^1.0.0-alpha.4",
}
```

or later version.

In **.angular-cli.json**

```
  "styles": [
    "../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js"
  ],
```

And to be able to use **M** object in your components, simply add to the imports

```
declare const M: any;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.
Add this to the head section of each HTML document.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
```

Then you can add classes to tags to add styles. There are lots of useful tutorials that can be found on google search. My favorite one is right here:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gCZ3y6mQpW0&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9gGrbtvASEZSlFEYBnPkmff&ab_channel=TheNetNinja

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thank you. I will fix that.