# Transforming jQuery code to pure JavaScript not showing anything

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to transform this little piece of code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.slider').slider();
});
```

to pure JavaScript code. I've followed some links and I've tried to rewrite the code above in two ways:

first option:

```
var slider2 = document.querySelectorAll(".slider");

window.onload = slider2.slider;
```

second option:

```
var slider2 = document.querySelectorAll(".slider");

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    slider2.slider();
});
```

In both cases I get no errors, but it doesn't show anything...

Any other ideas? :(

UPDATE: Ok, for some reason, the option with the DOM Events didn't work for me...

This is the code that I came up with that solved my problem:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.slider');

var instances = M.Slider.init(elems, {
    inDuration : 275
});

window.addEventListener("load", instances, false);
```

Initially I used just `window.onload = instances`, but I was using the same logic in another JS file, so I ended up overriding the other event. In the solution above, I got rid of that problem.

Comment: Where does the `slider` method in jQuery come from? If it's a jQuery plugin, you won't be able to call it without requiring that plugin as well

Comment: Check for errors in the browser console.

Comment: @CertainPerformance slider() is a method from Materialize CSS

Comment: Looks like it might be theoretically possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42353193/is-it-possible-to-use-materializecss-without-jquery

Comment: You could've looked that up in the manual: [`var instances = M.Slider.init(elems, options);`](https://materializecss.com/media.html)

Answer (score 2):

So `$('.slider').slider()` is not the same as `document.querySelectorAll(".slider")`. The former (using `$`) applies any jQuery plugins that exist, eg Materialize CSS's as you've mentioned you're using. The latter (`document.querySelectorAll`) does not as this is a native browser function.

So if you *really* want to use vanilla, you need to look at [Is it possible to use Materializecss without jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42353193/is-it-possible-to-use-materializecss-without-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

The method "querySelectorAll" returns a list (more precisely, [a NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)), so neither of those would do what you want.

Try the following (["DOMContentLoaded"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) is, i think the type of event you want):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.querySelector(".slider").slider();
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

From the [Materializecss documentation](https://materializecss.com/media.html#slider):

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.slider');
    var instances = M.Slider.init(elems, options);
  });
```

You can't use `.slider()` because that is meant to be called on a jquery instance since it is a jquery plugin.

Answer (score 0):

On this [website](https://materializecss.com/media.html#slider) slider can initiate in Javascript

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.slider');
        var instances = M.Slider.init(elems, options);
      });
```

And it is the same with jQuery:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slider').slider();
  });
```